# Attaching libraries in modules

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to attach a library in a custom shortcode but it doesn't show up neither using render array nor using attach_library twig function.

```
  class MyTimeline extends ShortcodeBase {
  public function process($attributes, $text, $langcode = Language::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED) {
    $output = [
      '#theme' => 'my_timeline_theme',
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array('my_timeline/timeline')
      ),
    ];
    return $this->render($output);
  }
```

mymodule/my_timeline_theme.html.twig

```
{{ attach_library('my_timeline/timeline') }}
```

The only way I can attach it is using this last line in the active theme,
ie node.html.twig

Comment: It is probably because you are rendering the output on your own. Why do you call the render method as part of the process method?

Comment: If I don't render it (I return the Array) I get a `Notice: Array to string conversion in Drupal\shortcode\Shortcode\ShortcodeService->processTag() (line 422 of modules/shortcode/src/Shortcode/ShortcodeService.php)`. and the word Array is printed instead of the rendered content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ShortcodeBase Class uses [renderplain](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3ArenderPlain/8.2.x) which strips 'the attached assets and cache tags'

In the comments to the source code they say: We use renderplain so that the shortcode's cache tags would not bubble up to the parent and affect cacheability. Shortcode should be part of contentand self-container.

In order to attach the library I then rendered the Array with this code:

```
$renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
return $renderer->render($output);
```

and it works. Need to understand if and how it affects cache, though.